# Background scrolling with open modal

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

I am frustrated. Really frustrated fighting the issue of background scrolling when a modal is open on mobile.

---

**Scenario** 
I open a modal on mobile.
Add a `.noScroll` class to the body in order to prevent background scrolling. Alas, the body in the background scrolls when a modal is open. Trying to tap/move slowly on the modal sometimes starts the scrolling in the modal, which is the desired result.

- I need the body to stay in position, so no `positon: fixed` or `absolute`
- I have  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`
- I have tried setting `top: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top+"px"` i.e. resolving the issue via JS

**CODE**:

*HTML*

```
<div id="galleryItem" class="modal_menu_item flexCenterX flexCenterY" style="display: flex;">
    <div class="modal_overlay"></div>
    <div class="modal_food_inner flexParent flexColumn">
        <span class="modal_close"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

        <div class="modal_food_info flexParent flexColumn flexCenterY">
            <h2 class="modal_food_info_title noMargin noPadding text-center">Keema Samosa</h2>
            <hr>
            <p class="modal_food_info_body noMargin">Crisp pastry filled with minced lamb, potato and peas served with homemade chutneys</p>
            <hr class="optional" style="display: block;">
        <span class="menu_food_item_priceContainer text-muted flexOne noPadding">€5.50</span></div>
    <img src="/pictures/55/vzrw5siuzogdeul8yaznqq4f.jpg" class="img-responsive modal_food_poster"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
body.noScroll {overflow: hidden;}

.modal_menu_item {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 9999999;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 }
.modal_overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh + 80px);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.modal_food_inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This issue seems a common one for mobiles. Though, at this point I'm somewhere between misery and desperation.

Help a programmer – Save a life

Answer (score 0):

When you adding this class .noScroll try to add in css when you adding this class when open modal

`body.noScroll {
overflow:hidden;
}`

Comment: Well... I thought that was obvious that the class `.noScroll` has such rule in my css

Comment: Try also this to add `overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;`